# Having to combine two functions in Hangman for the code to work (C)

Tags: c

My code wont work unless I combine two functions together (name_control and game_control). It has something to do with me returning a pointer. I am getting output that makes no sense. Any idea why?
Thank you for your help. Also any ideas on how to improve my code would be very much appreciated.

```
char *name_control(){
        //Names of the players
    char names[10][19]= {
        "lionel messi",
        "cristiano ronaldo",
        "ricardo kaka",
        "wayne rooney",
        "paul pogba",
        "paul scholes",
        "harry kane",
        "thierry henry",
        "david beckham",
        "mohamed salah"
    };
    int random;
    srand(time(NULL));
    random = rand() % 10 - 1;
    //Printintg the name out;
    for(int x = 0;x < 19;x++){
        if(names[random][x] == '\0')
        break;

        if(names[random][x] == ' ')
        printf(" ");

        if(names[random][x] != ' ')
        printf("-");
    }
    char *ptr = name[random];
    return ptr;
}

void game_control(){
    char *name = names[random];
    char answer;
    int game_over = 0;
    int guessed_values = 0;
    int stringlen = strlen(name);
    int wrong_answers = 0;
    int tracker;

    while(!game_over){
    tracker = 0;
    printf("\nPlease enter a letter\n");
    answer = getch();
    for(int x = 0; x < stringlen; x++){
        if(answer == name[x]){
            printf("poistion %d has a %c\n",(x+1),answer);
            guessed_values += 1;
            tracker +=1;
        }
    } 
    if(tracker == 0){
        printf("Try again. Wrong answer.\n");
        wrong_answers +=1;
    }
    if(wrong_answers == 5){
        printf("\nYou Lost!!");
        printf("%s",*name); 
        game_over = 1;
    }
    if(guessed_values == stringlen){
        printf("\nYou Won. Congrats!!");
        printf("%s",*name);       
        game_over = 1;
    }

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. What is the output that makes no sense? What should it be? The `name_control` function returns a pointer to a local variable which won't work because the local variables doesn't exist outside the function. Consider editing your question to include a [mcve] that clearly demonstrates the well described problem you're having.

Comment: **Welcome to Stackoverflow**, `to maximise your chance of getting an answer`, please **[take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)** and read **[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. `Update your question` with just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read **[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**.

Answer (score 0):

The `names` variable and data is created on the stack. As soon as the nane_control function exits, the area where that data is stored on the stack is reused elsewhere. As such returning a pointer to any part of that data would cause other parts of the program to access data that is no longer valid and will probably even crash your program. The solution is to move the `names` variable outside the function as a global variable, or to create the names data on the heap using the malloc function. To avoid repeating the same code, you could read the list from a file or better from a SQLite database.

Comment: @yano Did not do C for 3 decades. Thanks for the correction.